# Did I find a bug? Max-Width and min-width conflicts with transition

Tags: html, css

When I hover my mouse hover an .item element, it expands nicely.  But when I leave the .item element, there is a noticeable pause before the transition kicks in. After much troubleshooting, I narrowed it down to this line of code:

```
  max-width: 50%;
```

It appears when I set it up so an .item element cannot exceed more than 50%, it introduces a bug where the transition pauses briefly before executing. I experimented by removing max-width -- animation was butter smooth. I put it back in then removed transition; no pause at all.  It's only when the two are together that the pause is introduced.  I tried setting max-width to a defined number (max-width: 600px;) -- same result.  Switched it out with min-width, same result. Why would the two mess with each other?

This is the code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 558px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: flex 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  max-width: 50%;
}

.item:hover {
    flex-grow: 10;
}

video {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <video class="thevideo" muted loop>
                <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4#t=3" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <video class="thevideo" muted loop>
                <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4#t=3" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <video class="thevideo" muted loop>
                <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4#t=3" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <video class="thevideo" muted loop>
                <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4#t=3" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is not a bug, you did set the transition **only** on the flex propertie :)

Comment: It's not a bug. Try setting the hovered flex to 2 rather than 10. You'll see there is no pause when shrinking. At the 10 setting the width is more than the 50% max-width so the transition is closing down the width but you don't see the first part of it because of the max-width. Hence there appears to be a delay.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering a performance issue caused by the transition combined with the max-width property. This could be due to the browser's rendering engine trying to calculate the transition while also adjusting the maximum width dynamically.

Try using Use fixed width instead of percentage

```
.item {
    max-width: 600px; /* or any other fixed width value */
}
```

OR, Optimize the transition

```
.item {
    transition: max-width 0.6s ease; /* Adjust timing function if necessary */
}
```

Comment: I recognize this as output from GPT.  I know this because I already asked this to GPT and got the same exact answer.  

If you reviewed my question, you'd see I already tried fixed width instead of percentage.  Thanks though.

Comment: Please don't put up answers that are not only generated by AI but which are general stuff with options which you have not tested.